# In python, how can I remove the last character in a print that is also using line continuation? Tried rstrip()

Tags: python, string, line-continuation

I'm having a difficult time removing the final character in my line continuation print loop. Not sure if rstrip() is the correct solution or not.

It's my understanding that a ',' included at the end of a print statement i.e., 'print(),' will cause line continuation instead of creating a newline for each loop. The line continuation is desired, however I want to remove the last ',' from the print output.

I've tried various forms of print().rstrip(','), however it has either removed all of the ',' or resulted in a syntax error. Neither of which are desired.

`for attendee in attendees_at:
    print('[[image:%s]],' %(attendee),`

**Current output:**

[[image:aaa]], [[image:bbb]], [[image:ccc]],

**Undesired output, all of the trailing ',' have been removed:**

[[image:aaa]] [[image:bbb]] [[image:ccc]]

**Desired output is the same as the current output, however the last ',' is removed:**

[[image:aaa]], [[image:bbb]], [[image:ccc]]

Comment: Add `print'\b '`. <- that's a dirty dirty hack

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: It also only works under very limited conditions. It's the kind of thing that seems to work when you're trying it out interactively, only to completely fail when it goes into an autograder or a pipeline or any sort of processing that will see the actual backspace character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the easiest approach is to join the string **before** printing it:

```
print(", ".join("[[image:%s]]" % x for x in attendees_at))
```